# How can I create an onClick selection in a ListView

Tags: java, android

I have a `SQLite` db and I want to see in a ListView all the elements. But I want to make every row clickable. How to do this? Here is the code:
Then.. another question.. I have an activity that I can launched by the options menu and it add or remove data from the db.. I want to autoupdate the list when i come back to this activity.. How can I change the code?.

```
public class WorkflowChoice extends Activity {

private static final int INIT_JADE_PROFILE = 0;
private static final int MANAGE_DATABASE = 1;
private static final int MODIFY_FILES = 2;
private static final int CHANGE_THEME = 3;
private static final int SHOW_OUTPUT_WORKFLOW = 4;
private LinearLayout properties_container;

private MyDatabase db;
TextView wfsTv;
ListView wfsLv;
private Cursor c;

public MyDatabase getDb() {
    return db;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choice);

    properties_container = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.properties_container);

    String host = (String) InitJadeProperties.retrieve(this, getString(R.string.main_container_host), getString(R.string.default_host));
    String port = (String) InitJadeProperties.retrieve(this, getString(R.string.main_container_port), getString(R.string.default_port));

    wfsTv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wfsTv);
    ListView wfsLv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.wfsLv);

    db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
db.open();  //apriamo il db


if(db.fetchWfs().getCount()==0){//inserimento dati, solo se il db è vuoto

        db.insertWf("WF1", "class1");
        db.insertWf("WF2", "class2");
        db.insertWf("WF3", "class3");
        db.insertWf("WF4", "class4");
        db.insertWf("WF5", "class5"); 

}

c=db.fetchWfs(); // query
startManagingCursor(c);

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter( //semplice adapter per i cursor
                this, 
                R.layout.wfs, //il layout di ogni riga/prodotto 
                c, 
                new String[]{MyDatabase.WfMetaData.ID,MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY,MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY},//questi colonne 
                new int[]{R.id.IDTv,R.id.nameTv,R.id.classTv});//in queste views

wfsLv.setAdapter(adapter); //la listview ha questo adapter


//qui vediamo invece come reperire i dati e usarli, in questo caso li stampiamo in una textview

int nameCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY);  //indici delle colonne
int classCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY);       

if(c.moveToFirst()){  //se va alla prima entry, il cursore non è vuoto
        do {

                wfsTv.append("Wf Name:"+c.getString(nameCol)+", Class:"+c.getString(classCol)+"\n"); //estrazione dei dati dalla entry del cursor

                } while (c.moveToNext());//iteriamo al prossimo elemento
}

db.close();
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);   //visto che usiamo i gradient, usiamo questo trick (vedi snippet forum)
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);  

//wfsLv.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{Color.RED,Color.parseColor("#f2bf26")}));
//wfsTv.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{Color.RED,Color.parseColor("#f2bf26")}));
//definizione ed uso di gradient in modo programmatico


//animazioni in modo programmatico (vedi snippet forum)
Animation a1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
a1.setDuration(1000);
a1.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
wfsLv.startAnimation(a1);
//entra da sotto


Animation a2 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
a2.setDuration(1000);
a2.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
wfsTv.startAnimation(a2);
//entra da sopra


wfsLv.setClickable(true);
//e affidiamo la gestione del tap/click ad un apposito listener, che ci permetterà di agire sull’elemento cliccato e ricaricare la nostra lista

wfsLv.setOnItemClickListener
       (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
          View v, int position, long id) {
 TextView txtId = (TextView)
          v.findViewById(R.id.wfsTv); 
 c.requery(); 
}
       });

/*wfsTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CharSequence text = "Workflow scelto!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    });*/



    TextView masterTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.masterTv);
    masterTv.setText("Master");
    masterTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSubActivity();

        }
    });
}
private void startSubActivity(){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfigChoice.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your 1  st question i have

> 

```
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

// here you will get **position** of the item in the list which you can use gor updation/deletion

                }


            });
```

and for the second question

write your 2nd question-

write your listview intialization code in **onResume()** method so it will be getting called every time when you came back to this activity..

Comment: I've tried to modify the onResume() but without any good result.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You have an example at the Android documentation ListView tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
wfsLv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {

  }
});
```

Comment: If you see I use this.. but how can I launch a toast with the name of the class of the object cliked?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an xml file as a row of your listview. In your xml file just set the most outer layout as

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and all your child views as

```
android:clickable="false"
```

try this hope it will work.

then you can listen it in setonitemclicklistener